# Problem Sheets and Exercises for understanding the Ricci Flow

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

I have recently been attending a seminar on the Ricci flow and the instructor has asked if we could find some problem sheets or exercises related to the Ricci flow which we could go through together as he does not have any himself.

I have tried searching around but not found anything, did anyone have any recommendation or exercises that they know of somewhere on the Internet which would be worth going through?

Comment: How about just pick up some standard Ricci flow introductory books and treat all theorems as exercise?

Comment: I think we have pretty much already done that with the lecture notes by Peter Topping, we went through and basically proved everything in there.  There must surely be some general problems which can be done as well?